# number of tables in a database (android)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I use Count_tables method  for count the number of tables in database but always return one.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE abb1  ( _ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name  TEXT )");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE abb2  ( _ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name  TEXT )");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE abb3  ( _ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name  TEXT )");
}


public int Count_tables(){
    int count = 0;
    String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence'";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES, null);

    return cursor.getCount();;

}
```

Comment: probably change cursor.getCount(); to cursor.getInt(0); https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `select count(*)`. This will return a cursor with a single row and entry carrying the number tables. When you do `cursor.getCount()` on that, naturally you will always get 1.

You shoudl either use :

`int count = cursor.getInt(0)` - **Get number entry rather than row count of cursor returned by count(*)**

or

`String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT * FROM ...` - **Gets all tables names as rows in cursor. Doing `cursor.getCount()` on this cursor will return a valid value.**